# Diazo / XSLT - replace class of content in one of two places in theme

Tags: xslt, plone, diazo

Using Plone 4.3.x

**Basically:** How can I copy one set of elements from the content to place a and place b in a theme and in place b change an attribute of the copied elements?

**Specifically:** In my rules.xml file I am `<replace>`ing two `.replace-main-nav` in the theme.html with the children of `#navigation` from the content:

**rules.xml:**

```
<replace css:theme=".replace-main-nav"
         css:content-children="#navigation" />
```

**examples of places in theme.html:**

```
<div class="place-a">
    <del class="replace-main-nav"><!-- place nav here --></del>
</div>

<div class="place-b">
    <del class="replace-main-nav"><!-- place nav here again --></del>
</div>
```

**example of nav in content**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="foo">
            Item 1
        </li>
        <li class="foo">
            Item 2
        </li>
        <li class="foo">
            Item 3
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to replace the attribute `class="foo"` with `class="baa"` ONLY when the `<ul>` replaces `.replace-main-nav` in `.place-b`.

Is this possible?

If so how can I do it?

**What I want out**

```
<div class="place-a">        
    <ul>
        <li class="foo">
            Item 1
        </li>
        <li class="foo">
            Item 2
        </li>
        <li class="foo">
            Item 3
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="place-b">        
    <ul>
        <li class="baa">
            Item 1
        </li>
        <li class="baa">
            Item 2
        </li>
        <li class="baa">
            Item 3
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It probably is possible with some clever XSLT, but perhaps it's pertinent to ask: *why* do you want to swap "foo" for "baa"?  Can you not keep it as "foo" and then write a very specific CSS selector to style stuff (or select it for JS operation)?

Comment: I suppose I should have said the why. The different classes are required by a front-end framework that I am using. It is not straightforward and is prone to introduce bugs if I try to do `.place-b .foo`. I've also already crated a stop-gap JS solution but that feels nasty hacky. I'm really looking for assistance with the clever XSLT solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://plone-theming-with-diazo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snippets_diazo/recipes/index.html#move-plone-elements-around) helps?

So something like this? (which is not tested)

```
<replace css:content-children=".place-b">
  <ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="//*[@id='navigation']/*">
    <li class="baa">
      <xsl:copy-of select="./text()" />
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
</replace>
```

Comment: Thank you Danimal. This probably would do what I asked (with a little tweaking). I have just realised that my use-case is actually a lot more complicated with nested elements that need attributes adjusting too. Woot.